# Value missing from form.fieldnames in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I must be losing my mind.

```
<cfif cgi.request_method eq "POST">
    <cfoutput>
        Form.fieldnames = #form.fieldnames#<br>
        structKeyList(form) = #structKeyList(form)#
    </cfoutput>
</cfif>

<form  method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <input type="text" name="graduation_date" value="x"><br>
    <input type="text" name="foo" value="y"><br>
    <input type="text" name="bar" value="z"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" >

</form>
```

The `form.fieldnames` variable should include a list of submitted fields: `foo`, `bar`, and `graduation_date`. But `graduation_date` is missing.

After a little more testing, I see that anything ending in `_date` is excluded from `form.fieldnames`.

I was going to ask what's wrong with my code, but now I'm pretty convinced it's a bug in ColdFusion. (I'm on ColdFusion 8.0.1 / OS X 10.5.6.)

It's a bug in ColdFusion, right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe it's the [custom validation feature](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/validateData_10.html#1154690) (aka "Validating form data using hidden fields")?

Essentially, by using some specifically formatted form fields (`field_required`, `field_date`, `field_integer`, etc.) you can perform server-side validation of your forms.

This goes back several versions of ColdFusion, back when CFFORM wasn't very robust and keeps you from having to write validation code for every one of your form fields. There are better ways to do this now, but it's still in there for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Yes, apparently that's it. Still a bug IMHO, but it's good to know what the underlying cause is. And that I haven't lost my mind. :-)

Comment: It's not a bug, it's just a really bad decision that's been maintained for the sake of backwards compatibility.

Comment: I would still say it is a bug based on the fact that the fieldnames property should still show all fields submitted. These fields are still submitted.

Comment: There is still a bug in CF related to this. As of CF9, a flag exists to turn off this validation functionality, however the fields are *still* removed from the fieldnames property even when the behaviour has apparently been disabled.  
I've submitted a bug here: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4170204

Answer (score 0):

Yep I ran into this little problem as well with ColdFusion 8.  I was practically ready to flight test my server trying to figure out why a text box named "asof_date" was not being procesed nor was it showing up in the FIELDNAMES field in my posted data (which explains why it was being ignored).  I call this a bug in terms of orthogonality.  As soon as I changed the name to "pub_asof" it worked fine.  Argh!!

Comment: I have a rule of thumb to put data types as prefixes on my values/variables/field names (like dtAsof, dtCreated, aArray, szZeroBitString, nMyNumber, iMyInteger,  etc).